# How do you return certain properties from a linq query, rather than complete objects?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've just downloaded the Linq provider for NHibernate and am just a little excited. But I don't know Linq syntax that well.

I can return whole objects from a query like this:

```
var query = from foo in session.Linq<Kctc.BusinessLayer.Domain.Case>()
                  where foo.CaseNumber > 0
                  select foo;
```

And I can select a single property like this:

```
var query = from foo in session.Linq<Kctc.BusinessLayer.Domain.Case>()
                  where foo.CaseNumber > 0
                  select foo.Id;
```

But how would I select two properties, e.g. foo.Id and foo.Bar? Or is that not possible?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an anonymous projection:

```
var query = from foo in session.Linq<Kctc.BusinessLayer.Domain.Case>() 
              where foo.CaseNumber > 0 
              select new { foo.Id, foo.Bar };
```

Comment: Thanks to both Stephen and ck. I am so excited about this Linq business. It's the most exciting thing Ive found since jQuery. Why did it take me so long? :)

Comment: Oh my God, this is absolutely sick! :)

Comment: LINQ is indeed groundbreaking. Just wait until you find out about [LINQ to events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2010/07/07/rx-hands-on-labs-published.aspx). Then your mind will *really* start bending. :)

Comment: The page you linked to doesn't contain any mention of linq, or events (not in the programming context anyway). What is Linq to events?

Comment: Oh I see, asynchronous programming. Tasty.

Comment: That blog entry has a link to a PDF download. It's a gentle introduction to the Rx extensions library, which is nearing completion by Microsoft Research. The term "LINQ to events" refers to the underlying concept of the library: to treat asynchronous events (e.g., mouse move events) as a sequence of *data*. Once this conceptual leap is made, it's natural to use them in LINQ expressions, and this is exactly what Rx enables. Read the hands-on-lab for .NET for all the fun details.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Stephen, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new `Anonymous` type, that will only be available in the current scope (i.e. it can't be returned from a method etc.)

```
var query = from foo in session.Linq<Kctc.BusinessLayer.Domain.Case>() 
              where foo.CaseNumber > 0 
              select new { foo.Id, foo.Bar };
```

Or you can create a custom class and populate that.

Comment: Very interesting blog you've got there. Loved the article about slavery!